# Counting all occurances of a certain value in both of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL table have `2 columns (col1,col2)` I want to make query to get the count of cells where `value = 4`

I use `Select COUNT(*) from tbl where col1=4 OR col2=4`

But it give me 1 as they are in same row it should be 2 because (4) found 2 times

```
    col1       col2
-------------  -----------
5                 1
7                 3
4                 4
10                8
8                 21
2                 22
```

Comment: The fact that you wish to perform such a query strongly suggests poor schema design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add the result of two select statements. try this one

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE  col1 = 4 )+
(SELECT COUNT(*) from tbl WHERE  col2 = 4)
AS SumCount
```

> result would be: 2

Comment: I did try your code Dyrandz Famador, it works fine on sql engine I try to print it by PHP

Answer (score 0):

I think this will count the cells properly.  Including counting both col1 and col2 being 4 in the same row.

```
SELECT COUNT(IF(col1=4,N,NULL)) + COUNT(IF(col2=4,N,NULL)) cellcnt FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the two column into single column using `UNION ALL` then find the count. Try this.

```
select count(1) from
(
select col1 as col from yourtable
union all
select col2 from yourtable
)as a
where col = 4
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the following query to do what you desire

```
Select sum(col1=4)+sum(col2=4) from tbl where col1=4 OR col2=4
```